# Нужен ли индекс для TTL колонки, и ускорит ли это процесс удаления записей из таблицы YDB

Tags: ydb

В YDB есть возможность [автоматического удаления устаревших строк по TTL](https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/concepts/ttl).
Нужно ли добавлять на колонку с TTL индекс для ускорения удаления данных/снижения нагрузки на базу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не нужно.

Удаление строк по TTL работает без использование индекса. И его создание только замедлит удаление строк, т.к. нужно будет обновлять записи не только в основной таблице, но и в индексе.